# Parameterized Jenkins Pipeline: Choices not showing up

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, extended-choice-parameter

I am trying to setup my pipeline as a Parameterized Pipeline using Single_select choice parameters.

My pipeline header looks as follows:

```groovy
properties(
    [
        parameters([
            [
                $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
                description: 'Select your testcase', 
                filterable: false, 
                name: 'testCases', 
                choices: ['HappyFlow', 'NewYork_HappyFlow']
            ]
        ]
    ), 
        pipelineTriggers([])
    ]
)
```

What happens when I am running my pipeline is the following:

[image: Jenkins leaves the dropdown empty instead of giving me the options I specified in my pipeline properties]

Jenkins leaves the dropdown empty instead of giving me the options I specified in my pipeline properties

How would I get the dropdown to be filled with the parameters from my pipeline properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
   parameters([choice(choices:['HappyFlow', 'NewYork_HappyFlow'], description: 'Select your testcase', name: 'testCases')          
        ])
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer, I managed to get it working.

I did have to change out the standard array formatting to the suggested string format of @mkobit

The code that eventually worked for me looks like this:

`properties([parameters([choice(choices:'HappyFlow\nNewYork_HappyFlow',description: 'Select your testcase',name: 'testCases')
])])`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be affected by [JENKINS-26143: *Workflow Snippet Generator - Incorrect format for Input with Choice Parameter*](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26143). I think a fix is out for it in Jenkins 2.112 based on the comments on the issue, but for now, you can change `choices` from:

```
choices: ['HappyFlow', 'NewYork_HappyFlow']
```

to

```
choices: 'HappyFlow\nNewYork_HappyFlow'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was indeed aware of this bug, but ran into a formatting issue before running into this issue.

Your answer together with the answer of @codeGeass helped me out tremendously.